# GSuite Add-ons - Gmail Detect Recipient Email Change

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, gsuite-addons

Using GSuite Add-on, for Gmail, is there an event that can be used to fire a callback when a recipient email has been added/removed?

Comment: These are the [Google Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thanks. So I assume the answer is that there is not an events that fires when a recipient emails has been modified on an email if its not one of the events on the event object page?

Comment: As far as I know that’s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there an event that can be used to fire a callback when a recipient email has been added/removed?

#### Answer:

*No, there isn't. [There are no event objects for Gmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).*

#### Further Reading:

- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview)
- [Extending G Suite with Add-ons | G Suite Add-ons | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview)
- [Extending Gmail with G Suite Add-ons | G Suite Add-ons | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail)
- [Gmail actions | G Suite Add-ons | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/gmail-actions)